# Column names are not updating after using inner function for a generated csv table

Tags: python, pandas, csv, user-interface, pysimplegui

I'm having trouble with a section of code from my PySimpleGUI program. To make this direct as possible here are the steps that are being performed.

- CSV file is uploaded and an editable csv window is created
- Button is pressed ("Calculate Diplotype"), and the inner function (diplotype_calc()) is called
- The csv window is then updated with the manipulated Dataframe

The issue is in the last step. The data is correctly manipulated as intended by the inner function, but for the life of me, I cannot get the csv window to show the new column names, they stay the same as the initial upload. Any thoughts on how I could fix this update issue?

I will just add the inner function, as I think that is where the issue is. The outer function, csvwindow(), creates the csv window and displays the csv that was uploaded. The inner function, diplotype_calc(), does all of the manipulation. I will also add the imports im using at the top.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import webview
import pandas as pd
import csv
import os
import operator
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import tkinter.messagebox

# Diplotype Calculator Functions
    def diplotype_calc(file_path):
        data, allele_cols = read_csv_file(file_path)
        allele_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=allele_cols)[['sample ID', 'CYP2D6', 'CYP2C9']]
        print(allele_df)
        # Import CPIC dataframe from Google Cloud Storage into pandas dataframe
        # Currently only supported for CYP2D6 and CYP2C9
        cpic_data = f'https://storage.googleapis.com/pg-genotyping-cpic-2d6-2d9/2d6_2d9_joined.csv'
        cpic_df = pd.read_csv(cpic_data)

        # Merge the two DataFrames based on the common columns CYP2D6 and CYP2C9
        merged_df = pd.merge(allele_df, cpic_df, on=['CYP2D6', 'CYP2C9'])

        # Create two new columns to store the Metabolizer Status and Activity Score
        merged_df['Metabolizer Status'] = ''
        merged_df['Activity Score'] = ''

        # Create two dictionaries to store the metabolizer status and activity score for each call
        d6_status_dict = dict(zip(cpic_df['CYP2D6'], cpic_df['Metabolizer Status']))
        d9_status_dict = dict(zip(cpic_df['CYP2C9'], cpic_df['Metabolizer Status']))
        d6_activity_dict = dict(zip(cpic_df['CYP2D6'], cpic_df['Activity Score']))
        d9_activity_dict = dict(zip(cpic_df['CYP2C9'], cpic_df['Activity Score']))

        # Create two new columns to store the Metabolizer Status and Activity Score
        allele_df['Metabolizer Status'] = ''
        allele_df['Activity Score'] = ''

        # Iterate over each row of the allele DataFrame
        for index, row in allele_df.iterrows():
            # Get the cyp2d6 and cyp2c9 calls for the current sample ID
            cyp2d6_call = row['CYP2D6']
            cyp2c9_call = row['CYP2C9']

            # Use the dictionaries to get the metabolizer status and activity score for the current calls
            cyp2d6_status = d6_status_dict.get(cyp2d6_call, 'UND')
            cyp2c9_status = d9_status_dict.get(cyp2c9_call, 'UND')
            cyp2d6_activity = d6_activity_dict.get(cyp2d6_call, 'UND')
            cyp2c9_activity = d9_activity_dict.get(cyp2c9_call, 'UND')

            # Use the comparison results to populate the Metabolizer Status and Activity Score columns of the allele DataFrame
            allele_df.loc[index, 'Metabolizer Status'] = f'2D6: {cyp2d6_status} ||| 2C9: {cyp2c9_status}'
            allele_df.loc[index, 'Activity Score'] = f'{cyp2d6_activity}, {cyp2c9_activity}'

        # convert all of the updated data back into a list of lists
        updated_data = allele_df.values.tolist()
        # save_loc(allele_df)
        print(updated_data)
        window['-TABLE-'].update(values=updated_data)

        csv_window(updated_data)
```

I can provide the outer function if needed. Thank you ahead of time for the ideas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following statement only update the data in the table

```py
window['-TABLE-'].update(values=updated_data)
```

There's no method provided to update the headings of a Table element.

Demo code with tkinter code.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

font = ("Courier New", 20)

layout = [
    [sg.Table(
        [[f'Cell ({i}, {j})' for j in range(2)] for i in range(5)],
        headings=[f'Heading {i} - 0' for i in range(2)],
        justification='center',
        key='TABLE')],
    [sg.Push(), sg.Button('Update')],
]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout)
count = 0

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == "Update":
        count += 1
        for i in range(2):  # Update new headings
            window['TABLE'].widget.heading(i, text=f'Heading {i} - {count}')

window.close()
```

Comment: I swear its the smallest things I'm overlooking. Thank you for the help!